# As a Member is to a List, What is a List to a Member?

Tags: scope, terminology, theory

I'm not quite sure if this should be under cstheory.stackexchange.com, or here, but I'm posting it here because it feels less out of place to me.

---

This is a question about terminology.

A piece of data stored in an object is called a member. This could be storing an object in an array, an int in an object or an object in another object.

If I want to talk about an object accessing something it contains, I would say:
 `"Should foo be able to access it's member bar".`

What if I want to talk about the reverse in abstract?
`"Should bar be able to access it's ___, foo".`

---

Some examples:

- What is a game's map to the objects it stores?
- What is a game-state to a map and user interface that it stores?
- What is a renderer to the objects it renders (potentially different?)

Comment: I think "container" is a good term, atleast while programming.

Comment: In some cases, I would agree. In other cases however the (word I need) does more than contain. I feel like "Lower level of abstraction" is heading in the right direction, but I don't feel its right.

Comment: I wouldn't use a generic term like `member` you used for the other case. The nature of the container would change the context quite a bit. I'd use a concrete term like "can the objects access the map?" (for the game example) or "can the objects being rendered access attributes of the renderer?"